# How can I write following vector to csv file in r

Tags: r

["tst2" is a matrix. I have converted in vector as C(tst2). I would like to write this vector/matrix into csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf96Z.png)

Comment: Please do not present code or data as an image as it makes your question, as of 2017, unsearchable. As such it's almost useless to anyone else. You can greatly improve it by presenting the data, code and the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes a csv-file from your matrix/vector into your current working directory.

```
write.csv(tst2, file = "filename.csv")
```